Should I have said anything to my team member with the feedback I got at work sponsored social event?
I am a manager within the cybersecurity division where I work. I am in the United States and this event occurs in the USA. I have a team of 10 people.
Recently, I was at a my company's regional headquarters attending a divisional event sponsored by senior management. The itinerary included a team social event after formal work hours (9 - 5 EST) that is open to all attending with the aim to socialize with colleagues outside one's immediate team.
A cash bar was onsite where folks can order drinks. 1 free drink was offered to all attendees and one can purchase more drinks afterwards, with no strict enforced limit (i.e: outside of social norms and professionalism). I had a few drinks and was really enjoying myself, socially talking with colleagues, singing karaoke, and playing board games alongside trivia. The same applied to my team members.
I was surprised that other divisional ( non team) and non - management level employees said one of my team members , while not behaving inappropriately or being overtly intoxicated, was showing the below:

More talkative and talking more loudly than usual

Animated emotions and more frequent laughter

Much more open with sharing of personal life

Disinhibted singing Karaoke and taking pictures with colleagues


At time of comment, I was buzzed and the folks who gave me the feedback also  had been drinking. I saw the feedback as an indication that folks were having a good time, and not as a complaint of unprofessional conduct , deserving reprimand.
Question

Should I have said anything to my team member the day after?

Should I own my team members behavior as their direct manager?

What , if anything, should I have said to the divisional employees who provided me with the above information on my team member?



Was there someone who after the fact suggested that you do any of the above. Or are you inferring that you should say something, when in fact no explicit recommendation to do so was made

@TheDemonLord , that's my dilemma. I was not sure whether the feedback was a veiled complaint of overstepping social norms at work, or just factual observation. No ask was said to me

I'm unclear why you were surprised at people commenting on out-of-character behaviour. It's kind of what people do? Or do you mean you were surprised at your team member's behaviour?

Is there something that gives you the impression these were negative comments? They seem pretty consistent with this being a social event where there is even a modicum of alcohol. Perhaps they were also of the view that it's good to see people relaxing away from the office? Perhaps the person in question is more introverted than most in the office setting ?

Assuming the behavior was "generally acceptable" this one is straight forward.

Should I have said anything to my team member the day after?

No. What exactly is there to talk about? "Hey, you sure loosen up a bit when you have a few drinks"??? That's really none of your business.

Should I own my team members behavior as their direct manager?

In company sponsored settings you kind of do and it's to a bad idea to keep an eye out and make sure no one embarrasses themselves too much. But as long as the behavior was not particularly out of line, there was nothing to be done.

What , if anything, should I have said to the divisional employees who provided me with the above information on my team member?

The polite version of "bugger off. What business of yours is it?". Even if the behavior was a little inappropriate, commenting on it is equally inappropriate, so I'm guessing the commenter had a few drinks too.
Example: Comment: "Hey manager, it looks Sydney sure is having extra fun tonight" Answer: "I'm glad they are enjoying themselves. Do you have an issue with that?"

The last line - I would drop the Do you have an issue with that, I would go with the positive line of: It is refreshing to see that side of them!

@TheDemonLord: I added that line specifically to let the person know that this feedback is unwanted and slightly inappropriate. Commenting on other people's behavior (if it's inside acceptable norms) is just gossiping and unprofessional.

Similar to TheDemonLord, I would respond more along the lines of "Yah, isn't it great! It's great to see them having a good time. How's your team enjoying themselves?"

@TheDemonLord It might be that they are politely signaling that they're finding Sydney's behavior to be a bit much. I'd keep the question, but phrase it in a less hostile, more subtle or joking way - "hope they're not breaking any tables", or something like that.

Should " it's to a bad idea" be " it's not a bad idea"?

Absent any ask to reprimend them - I would read the list more as an observation about different behavior.
Introverts getting a bit of Dutch Courage and becoming Extroverted. The only part that might raise an eyebrow is the line about sharing more about their personal life.
So long as they arent telling others about their Waifu body pillow collection or insert other NSFW activity - then I would let it slide.
If you are really unsure - maybe at the next team meeting have a couple of lines about how good it was to see everyone in a more relaxed and informal setting and then also a line about moderating alcohol consumption at a work function.
Perhaps a little self-deprecating, so it doesnt feel like attacking the team - e.g.
I think next time though, I might stop at 3 beers, I dont know about everyone else but I got a little chatty after the 4th.
